# Nested Cross-Validation with Small dataset

Tags: cross-validation, small-sample, selection-bias

I am currently working with a small dataset (only 175 samples, 45 features) and have been reading on the proper way to cross-validate my model. I had started with a basic cross-validation using a grid search, but have seen that a nested CV structure is superior as it reduces both bias in the model and model selection bias post-CV.

The issue I have is that with a small dataset I am worried about having an insufficiently sized training set in my inner loop since I will need to set aside part of the dataset for inner and out validation. I am using 5-fold CV with 3 repeats as the hyperparameter tuning CV in my inner loop.

Is my concern valid? Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: If you do not have enough data for nested cross validation then don't do it. You will have to make some compromises.